# Handling Multiple Gamepad with new Unity Input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, gamepad

Basically i want to use **2 GamePad controllers** on my game with the new Input System of unity. I'm working with **Unity2019-2.5f1**. I am using the **last Input Manager** provided. *(Specific package to install, not the default one)*.

The thing is that when i'm doing my **"Input Actions"** map through the editor, i don't have any any place to specify that i need to bind one Controller to one Action Map. So in the end when my controller is plugged and used it basically **control 2 players**.

*I already tried to duplicate any level of hierarchy of the Input Actions map
to see if Unity handle it by itself (which i would be surprised but as you can see it's not the case).*

I **Also grind Google & Youtube** to find something but every documentation that i found didn't **specifically talked about 2 GamePad** or were using the **old Input system** (the one with strings).

```cs
//Each of those Variable are two different InputAction maps.

Controls controls = new Controls();
CharacterSelection controls2 = new CharacterSelection();

//The move action is already bind to a joystick and works well when i only have to handle one player.

controls.Page1.Move.performed += ctx => print("First GamePad");
controls2.Page1.Move.performed += ctx => print("Second GamePad");
```

*And when i move the joystick :*

```
First GamePad

Second GamePad
```

*is printed*

Comment: Use PlayerInput and PlayerInputManager if you want local multiplayer.